# Why same variable declaration for two FOR loops is right?

Tags: c

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++) { do something }
```

has equivalent while loop :

```
int i = 0;
while(i<n) {
  do something
  i++;
}
```

Now,

```
for(int i = 4 ; false ; );
print i;//prints 4
for(int i = 7 ; false ; );
print i;//prints 7
```

according to my understanding, must be equivalent to :

```
int i = 4;
while(false);
int i = 7;
while(false);
```

which is two times declaration for 'i'. And, obvious error.

Now, Why there is no redeclaration error for 'i' in for loops?

**code ran after giving two warnings :**

**warning: name lookup of 'i1' changed for new ANSI 'for' scoping**

**warning:   using obsolete binding at 'i1'**

Comment: This is not `C`, maybe `C++`? Please add the right tag

Comment: `print i;//prints 4` and `print i;//prints 7` won't compile

Comment: After running code, i asked here.

Comment: Please post an [mcve], giving details about the warnings and errors you get and your compiler.

Comment: used JFE and GCC (according to what i know JFE is editor, and GCC is running environment)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the scope of a 'while' and 'for' loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880658/what-is-the-scope-of-a-while-and-for-loop)

Comment: @Nasr: Why is this not C? (let alone the wrong `print` statements).

Comment: gcc is not an environment, but the compiler. And the `print` statements will definitively not compile.

Comment: @Olaf When declare value inside `for` loop i get compilation error in `c` like in here `for(int i=0; i<8; i++)`, i always declare it before the while loop then use it. correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Nasr: No you do not. Unless you use some crappy non-standard/ancient compiler. And you do not just have to _declare_, but to _define_! A definition as given is perfectly valid, but is not identical to the `while` variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft made an extension for their compilers, if enabled, the scope of `for` loop variables is extended to the outer scope, and the example would not compile. This is not standard compliant anymore, it's a historical relict. The extension can be disabled in the project settings.

Comment: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx)

Comment: @4566976 so it is some settings error? if i make the settings right. it will not compile?

Comment: @user3104225 As you use gcc this is not relevant. It's for Microsofts compiler cl.exe.

Comment: @4566976 I am not sure if it is Microsoft's cl compiler. I am using Microsoft OS, so probably yes.

Comment: @4566976 If you dont mind, i just have one more thing to ask. isn't it obvious that a variable is set to retain it's value after the loop, if it is declared outside(before) for loop? Then, why there is need to mention that "index variable i retains it's value when the loop terminates"

Comment: I think it's just a bit an unlucky wording for saying "the scope is extended".

Answer (score 2):

No They are not equal

```
for(int i = 4 ; false ; ); // scope of i is within for 
print i; // This is a compilation error
for(int i = 7 ; false ; ); // scope of i is within for loop
print i; // This is a compilation error
```

Where as here

```
int i = 4; // scope is not strictly blocked hence 
while(false);
int i = 7; // re declaration error for this
while(false);
```

Comment: isn't `while(false)` an infinite loop, and makes the system crash?

Comment: @Nasr Infinite loops won't make a crash. BTW, that loop isn't an infinite loop. It won't even run once. Were you thinking of `while(true)`?

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes you are right, misread here :) but infinite loop running on OS will make a crash (Depending on the OS), right?

Comment: @Nasr I don't know it exactly, but AFAIK, no. Also, I think that infinite loops like `while(true);` will be removed by modern compilers to enhance performance.

Comment: @Nasr infinite loop won't make the system crash, it just runs **forever**. However if each iteration it requests for more resources like memory, disk space... undefined behavior will happen, which may result in a crash. Just try some simple infinite loop and you'll see that the program only takes 100% of a CPU.