# go variable scope and shadowing

Tags: go

This is an example from GOPL - "The expressions x[i] and x + 'A' - 'a' each refer to a declaration of x from an outer block; we'll explain this in a moment."

The explanation never comes. Why is x[i] referring to the x in the outer scope? As soon as you redeclare x in an inner block it should shadow the x in the outer block. Why does this work?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := "hello!"
    for i := 0; i < len(x); i++ {
        x := x[i]
        if x != '!' {
            x := x + 'A' - 'a'
            fmt.Printf("%c", x)
        }
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/NQxfkTeGzA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:=` operator creates a new variable and assigns the right hand side value to it.

At the first iteration of the for loop, in the step `x := x[i]`, the only `x` the right hand side sees is the `x` defined in the step `x := "hello!"`. As far as the right hand side sees `x` is not redeclared yet.

> As soon as you redeclare x in an inner block..

It *is* not yet. Its redeclared only after `x := x[i]`.

And at the end of the iteration the new `x`'s scope ends. It is not reused in a new iteration.

When a new iteration happens its the same thing all over again.

Comment: Ah so each iteration of the loop is a new scope.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880658/what-is-the-scope-of-a-while-and-for-loop