# do for loops deallocate memory after they finish

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, memory-management

Let's say you wrote a for loop:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
```

Is that for loop creating 10 different `j` variables, and does it deallocate `i` and `j` after its done looping?

I have seen many people do this instead:

```cpp
int i, j, k

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
//..All The Loops..//
```

Is there any advantage of declaring the `i` `j` `k` variables before all of your loops, or is it just a personal preference?

Comment: I think you should take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880658/what-is-the-scope-of-a-while-and-for-loop

Comment: The place of variable declaration in the C source has very little to do with when the compiler actually allocates that variable. In practice, it will reserve registers or stack space for those variables at some point before they are used, then re-use that same register/stack space over and over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the variables in question are being created in [*automatic* storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). They are destroyed when they go [out of scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). The two examples are simply declaring the variables in different scopes.

In the first example, `i` is scoped to the outer loop, meaning `i` exists only while the loop is running. It is created when the loop begins, and it is destroyed when the loop ends:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { <- created here
    <statements>
} <- destroyed here
```

Same with `j` in the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { <- i created here
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { <- j created here
       <statements>
    } <- j destroyed here
} <- i destroyed here
```

In the second example, the variables are scoped to the outer block which the loops exist in.  So the variables already exist before the outer loop begins, and they continue to exist after the loop ends.

```cpp
{
    ...
    int i, j, k; <- created here

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
           ...

    ...
} <- destroyed here
```

Comment: In C, scope and lifetime are orthogonal. I accept that the distinction can appear pedantic, especially for beginners, but it's real.

Comment: So there isn't a advantage in declaring them outside of the loop in ``c`` or ``c++`` they get deleted the moment their curly brace ends.
If i understood the answer correctly.

Comment: @Pixel Paras: if you need the last value of the iteration variable after the for loop has ended, then you must declare it before/outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`  are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode, it's a more modern style.

You should declare `i` before use it when worked with very old compiler.

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a comment. You have 51 reputation, so you can comment now.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I disagree, that answers the second question. Decalring before was not a still but required for old standards. (and so some people continue to use the old way).